# Holomorphic bounded function with discontinuous boundary function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for a holomorphic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}_+$, the right half plane, that is bounded and satisfies $f(s) = f(\frac{1}{s})$. In addition, it needs to have a discontinuous boundary function, defined as $f^* = \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0}f(\alpha + i\omega), \alpha \gt 0, \omega \in \mathbb{R}$.

I thought of $f(s) = s + \frac{1}{s}$, but it is not bounded on $\mathbb{C}_+$. I also thought of constant functions, but their boundary functions are the functions themselves, so continuous.

The requirements of holomorphicity, boundedness and boundary discontinuity seem contradictory. How do I find such a function?

Comment: Any integral along the imaginary axis over the boundary values with the Cauchy kernel $dy/(z-y)$ and a holomorphic function $f(z)$ with decay faster the 1/r in the right half plane. In this construction the integral of the closed contour on axis + half circle converges to the integral over the imaginary axis as $r\to \infty$.